# Transmit images from one mobile device to another in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am building app for windows phone 7,where i am taking screenshot in microsecond ,now my target is to pass screenshot from one device to another (i mean screen sharing)
anyone please tell me how can i do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Due to restriction of Our Windows Phone You can't do that by using Bluetooth or NFC in WP7 but there is a another way to do it just upload it to cloud database and you can access that cloud database using another phone and save image over there............

For that you can use,
 + Windows Azure
 + eBuddy
 + Skydrive public Folder
 + Dropbox public folder